# What is typ ( in a datasheet )

Tags: datasheet

What does typ stand for in this table?

It's in a IC datasheet.

[image: Table]

Comment: **typical** - normal value with in the boundaries of Minimum and Maximum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

typ stands for typical.

This is the typical value of the specification a part; the actual distribution of a population of parts will vary, but the typical value should be representative of the distribution of a large population of parts.

Sometimes a parameter will have a typical value and no minimum and/or maximum values in a data sheet.  In this case, the value of this parameter is not gauranteed by the manufacturer.  If a specification has a minimum or maximum value, it is usually gauranteed by production test or gauranteed by design.

Answer (score 2):

typ stands for typical. Min and max are guarranteed specifications.

Because semiconductors often have a spread of performance, always designing to the guaranteed specifications could result in having a too conservative design. The typical performance is what you can expect for 'most' parts. The guaranteed performance will not be exceeded for all parts.

What 'most' means depends on the manufacturer. The more reputable suppliers will actually have a specification for typical. For instance, when I was in industry, more than 90% of our output had to meet our typical specification. However, I am sure there are suppliers for whom 'typical' means 'I did once see one that nearly met that!'